# Primary Key problems when importing

Tags: sql, primary-key, navicat

I am building a database and have set field A, Release #, as the primary field.  I am running into a problem where duplicate keys are found which gives error on import.
Specifically, release # "49221" is the value of a certain release from a certain website.  On a different website, the release # is "0000000049221"

Release# 49221 is a completely different release than is "0000000049221".  Is there a way for me to import both of them into the same table while still retaining field "release #" as the primary key?

Comment: What is the data type of the field? If it's int, the db will ignore leading zeros, making the two values identical.

Comment: The data type of the field is bigint(13), I think that is exactly what happened.  Learning from scratch here and this is great to know, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually happens when implicit conversions are given, check the type of your primary key.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
  COLUMN_1 INT,
  COLUMN_2 VARCHAR(8)
)

INSERT INTO TEST
VALUES (4566,'00004566')

SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE COLUMN_1 = COLUMN_2
```

The second column , it converts to int, and the zeros at the left dissapear, Because zeros at the left in a number has not value (as you know).

Change the second column type to type varchar or char.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define the primary key as a CHAR or VARCHAR instead of an integer value.